# How to fix issue where I'm getting thousands of errors from prettier in my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

I am encountering this issue where prettier is giving me in excess of 1000 errors. I'm not sure what is causing it however here is how I got to this issue. I followed TraversyMedias guide on youtube to install eslint and prettier with the airbnb template. It was working great. I programmed for close to a day with it. Then after I started switching a component I had from React hooks state to Redux state I got an error saying that a file couldn't be found. After I fixed the issue it still was coming up with this error. I restarted my dev server and got a different error entirely it was an issue with the version of eslint i had. I can't remember the specific error but it was something along these lines "The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency: "eslint": "^7.11.0". " After I got that error I followed these steps
To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
Delete node_modules in your project folder.
Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

after I did that I encountered the error I am asking the question about.

some useful information My project structure is a top level project folder. it contains both my server and client folder and all three have their own package.json.

I look on this forum for someone with an error similar to mine and couldn't find any.
I googled many different worded questions about this issue and can't find anything on it.
I uninstalled prettier to see if it would go away. it didn't
here is what my package.json looks like in this order root folder client folder and server folder

```
{
  "name": "sac-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run dev\" \"cd client && npm start\" "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-node": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
{
    "name": "sac-web",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
        "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint": "^7.28.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
        "redux": "^4.1.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
        "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
        "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0"
    }
}

{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "The server for the sac website",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "dev": "nodemon app.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.12.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
    }
}
```

Any help you guys could give me would be fantastic. And please pardon me if I asked this question wrong. It is my first time asking any question on a programming forum.

Comment: The 'issue' is that with React 17, they have set it up so that nearly everything is an error and it is up to the developer to setup the configurations to say what is ok and what isnt. You need to create a .eslintrc.json and configure it

Comment: In my client/src I have an .eslintrc.json that looks like this.
     `{"extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "import/extensions": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "no-console": "off",
        "func-names": "off",
        "object-shorthand": "off",
        "indent": ["error", 2]
    }
}
`

Comment: Can you give an example of what prettier errors you are getting too?

Comment: [1]   Line 31:1:   Replace `····)·:·(␍` with `··)·:·(`                                                                                                                                                                                                  prettier/prettier
[1]   Line 31:1:   Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                                                                                                                                                                                         indent
[1]   Line 32:1:   Replace `········<Route␍` with `····<Route`

Answer (score 1):

The error I was getting had something to do with how eslint was set up or how prettier was set up. I deleted everything that was related to that and now the project is working.

Answer (score 0):

In a React 17 project I wanted to run, there were 2 .ignore files: `.prettierignore` and `.eslintignore`.

I added the src folder to these files and with that the errors disappeared.

This way you don't have to remove everything, and you can leave it to address it at a later time if you want.